# $360\times 60$ nautical mile is not equal with $6400$ km of earth radius

Tags: geometry

One degree on a great circle of earth equals to $60$ Nautical Miles. Hence:

$\ 360 \times 60 = 21,600$ M (Nautical Mile)

$\ 21,600M \times 1852$ Meters $= 40,003,200$ Meters $= 40,003.2$ Kilometers

While the radius of earth is $6400$ Kilometers. What is problem with my calculation?

**UPDATE:** The question is wrong in nature. I confused the radius of earth with circumference of the earth!

Comment: You have found the _circumference_ of the Earth! Dividing by $2\pi$ does give you something in the ballpark of 6400 km.

Comment: Stupid me! I confused radius of earth with circumference of earth. Thank you @Zen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to divide by $2\pi$ to get the radius.  You have calculated the circumference.